# Detect rows in a column containing only emojis in a data frame

Tags: python, regex, string, dataframe, nlp

How to detect rows in a column containing only emojis in a data frame? The rows containing text with emojis will not be considered.

Given DF:

### content

Wow Amazing!!!

I am loving it

Rocking

Not Recommended

Expected Output:

### content

I tried:

```
df = df[df['content'].str.contains(r'[\u263a-\U0001f645]')]
df.head()
```

But it shows all emojis including text.

Answer (score 1):

This is the current Unicode 15 regex that matches emoji.

```
(?:[0-9#*]️⃣|[☝✊-✍-------][-]?|⛓(?:️‍)?|[⛹](?:️‍[♀♂]️|[-](?:‍[♀♂]️)?)?|❤(?:️‍[])?|[--]|[---]|[---]|[]|[-]|[-]|[---]|[]|[---]|[]|[-]|[--]|[--]|[-]||[---]||[]|[----]|[--]|[]|[]|[]||[]|[]|(?:‍)?|(?:‍)?|[](?:‍(?:[♀♂]️(?:‍➡️)?|➡️)|[-](?:‍(?:[♀♂]️(?:‍➡️)?|➡️))?)?|[---](?:‍[♀♂]️|[-](?:‍[♀♂]️)?)?|(?:️‍(?:⚧️|))?|(?:‍☠️|(?:(?:|))?)?|(?:‍⬛)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍[⬛])?|(?:‍❄️)?|(?:️‍️)?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?|[]‍(?:(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?)|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-])|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?)?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:[]|‍[])|(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?|‍(?:(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?)|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-])|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?)?|[](?:‍[♀♂]️)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍️)?|(?:‍[↔↕]️)?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|‍|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]|(?:‍)?(?:‍)?)|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?)?|[©®‼⁉™ℹ↔-↙↩↪⌚⌛⌨⏏⏩-⏳⏸-⏺Ⓜ▪▫▶◀◻-◾☀-☄☎☑☔☕☘☠☢☣☦☪☮☯☸-☺♀♂♈-♓♟♠♣♥♦♨♻♾♿⚒-⚗⚙⚛⚜⚠⚡⚧⚪⚫⚰⚱⚽⚾⛄⛅⛈⛎⛏⛑⛔⛩⛪⛰-⛵⛷⛸⛺⛽✂✅✈✉✏✒✔✖✝✡✨✳✴❄❇❌❎❓-❕❗❣➕-➗➡➰➿⤴⤵⬅-⬇⬛⬜⭐⭕〰〽㊗㊙--------------------------------------------------------]|(?:(?:‍[-])?|(?:‍[-])?|(?:‍[])?|(?:‍[-])?|(?:‍[-])?)?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/kjOyuI/1

You can leverage this to exclude  lines with non-emoji text included.
Note this works on all lines at once. You can pare it down to one line at a time.

```
(?m)^(?!(?:[0-9#*]️⃣|[☝✊-✍-------][-]?|⛓(?:️‍)?|[⛹](?:️‍[♀♂]️|[-](?:‍[♀♂]️)?)?|❤(?:️‍[])?|[--]|[---]|[---]|[]|[-]|[-]|[---]|[]|[---]|[]|[-]|[--]|[--]|[-]||[---]||[]|[----]|[--]|[]|[]|[]||[]|[]|(?:‍)?|(?:‍)?|[](?:‍(?:[♀♂]️(?:‍➡️)?|➡️)|[-](?:‍(?:[♀♂]️(?:‍➡️)?|➡️))?)?|[---](?:‍[♀♂]️|[-](?:‍[♀♂]️)?)?|(?:️‍(?:⚧️|))?|(?:‍☠️|(?:(?:|))?)?|(?:‍⬛)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍[⬛])?|(?:‍❄️)?|(?:️‍️)?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?|[]‍(?:(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?)|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-])|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?)?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:[]|‍[])|(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?|‍(?:(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?)|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-])|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?)?|[](?:‍[♀♂]️)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍️)?|(?:‍[↔↕]️)?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|‍|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]|(?:‍)?(?:‍)?)|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️|❤️‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[](?:‍➡️)?|[-]))?)?|[©®‼⁉™ℹ↔-↙↩↪⌚⌛⌨⏏⏩-⏳⏸-⏺Ⓜ▪▫▶◀◻-◾☀-☄☎☑☔☕☘☠☢☣☦☪☮☯☸-☺♀♂♈-♓♟♠♣♥♦♨♻♾♿⚒-⚗⚙⚛⚜⚠⚡⚧⚪⚫⚰⚱⚽⚾⛄⛅⛈⛎⛏⛑⛔⛩⛪⛰-⛵⛷⛸⛺⛽✂✅✈✉✏✒✔✖✝✡✨✳✴❄❇❌❎❓-❕❗❣➕-➗➡➰➿⤴⤵⬅-⬇⬛⬜⭐⭕〰〽㊗㊙--------------------------------------------------------]|(?:(?:‍[-])?|(?:‍[-])?|(?:‍[])?|(?:‍[-])?|(?:‍[-])?)?)+$).*$\s*
```

https://regex101.com/r/81lRPh/1